# Prove that $\int_0^x e^{x^2}$ ~ $ \frac{1}{2x}e^{x^2}$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

My solution is:

Equivalence means that the limit of quotient is equal to zero.

Apply L'Hôpital's rule: $$\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int \limits_0^x e^{x^2}}{\frac{1}{2x}e^{x^2}} = \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2}(1 - \frac{1}{2x^2})} = \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

Am I missing something in my solution or is it ok?

Comment: You need a product or quotient rule in the denominator.

Comment: define your integral as $ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{2xe^{x^{2}}{2x} $ now integrate by parts to get a series expansion in 'x'

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: The second last step should be $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2 x^2}}$$ instead of $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1}$$ because you are still taking limit. Also, the notation $\sim$ usually means "asymptotically equivalent to", it requires the limit to be $1$ instead of $<\infty$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) for details. Otherwise, it looks okay to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is computed (almost) correctly: the derivative of
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{2x}e^{x^2}
$$
is
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{1}{2x^2}e^{x^2}+e^{x^2}=e^{x^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)
$$
whereas the derivative of $f(x)=\int_{0}^xe^{t^2}\,dt$ is
$$
f'(x)=e^{x^2}
$$
Since both $f$ and $g$ have $\infty$ as limit at $\infty$, you can apply l’Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2x^2}}=1
$$
I'd avoid writing $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1}$, though: it's clear what you mean, but you're not allowed to remove $-1/(2x^2)$.

And the limit being $1$ allows you to say that $f(x)\underset{x\to\infty}{\sim}g(x)$ (your reference to the limit being $0$ is incorrect).